# Stuck on laravel validation

Tags: validation, laravel

i'm trying to create back end UI of my website. User with admin access can login into the admin section and then edit registered users details.

i have a script which displays list of all registered users. When admin clicks on the name of a particular user, the details of that user is displayed in a form. The inputs of form contains previously stored values.

Now, what i want is if admin wants to change the email or username of that user, the new values should be unique. SO i added validation rule of unique in the validation rules of email and username.

```
$rules = array(
                'name'=>'min:2',
                'email'=>'email|unique:users',
                'username'=>'min:5|unique:users',
                'password'=>'min:5',
                'cpassword'=>'required_with:password|same:password'
            );
```

Now if the admin wants to change the name, then the form doesn't processes forward and gives an error that username and email should be unique because this is what i have written in the rules.

Then i created a hidden field(named id) in the form, which contained id of that particular user. I checked the value of the id by echoing `$id = Input::get('id')` and it displayed id of that particular user.

i tried to use this id in the rules:

```
$rules = array(
                'name'=>'min:2',
                'email'=>'email|unique:users,email,$id',
                'username'=>'min:5|unique:users,username,$id',
                'password'=>'min:5',
                'cpassword'=>'required_with:password|same:password'
            );
```

But still I'm getting errors on form submission that email and username should be unique. Why is it still showing error when i have already mentioned to ignore the user's id while checking uniqueness?

Answer (score 0):

on Single quote variable will not work i mean '$variable' won't print the vairiable value instead it will parse $ as string . you should use "$variable" . look here variable is under single quote .. thats a silly mistake php coder do lol.
edit this line

```
'username'=>'min:5|unique:users,username,$id',
```

to

```
'username'=>"min:5|unique:users,username,$id",
```

or this 
all goes same for email field too

```
'username'=>'min:5|unique:users,username,'.$id,
```